# simple_form default value is not been displayed.

Tags: ruby-on-rails, simple-form

I am using simple form to display on input field.

```
<%= f.input :timer, label: 'Duration', input_html: { value: '2' } %>
```

The value is been assigned correctly but it's not appearing on the screen, 
 when I trace the dom I get the following.

```
<input value="2" class="numeric integer optional" min="1" type="number" step="1" name="course[timer]" id="course_timer">
  #shadow-root (user-agent)
    <div id="text-field-container" pseudo="-webkit-textfield-decoration-container">
    <div id="editing-view-port">
      <div id="inner-editor"></div>
      </div>
      <div pseudo="-webkit-inner-spin-button" id="spin">
      </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: The input tag looks like it would be ok.  Is your css making it disappear?  In chrome dev tools, delete the classes from it and see if it reappears.  I have no idea what that #shadow-root stuff is about.

Comment: Weird. I tried it and it worked with text/string fields. But I saw the same behavior you saw when I tried it with a boolean--the init value was not shown on the form I use Simple_form, so I'm going to look into this more. If I find an answer will post.

Comment: If I copy and paste the input field outside the container it works fine, it doesn't work when I delete all the css only if I remove the container div.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This worked for me, use the n value, not the 'n' form:

```
<%= f.input :timer, label: 'Duration', input_html: { value: 2 } %>
```

My default input value persists on the form. Here's the rendered html from my own test. Added the divs you have, including the webkit spinner and still okay.

```
    <div class="form-group decimal optional location_rating"><label class="decimal optional control-label" for="location_rating">Ratings average</label><input value="1" class="numeric decimal optional form-control" type="number" step="any" name="location[rating]" id="location_rating" /></div>
       <div id="text-field-container" pseudo="-webkit-textfield-decoration-container">
        <div id="editing-view-port">
         <div id="inner-editor"></div>
         </div>
         <div pseudo="-webkit-inner-spin-button" id="spin">
         </div>
    </div>
```

Screen capture
[image]

For what it's worth. Maybe it helps you narrow down the problem field.

Comment: No it didn't work for me, it's been displayed for a moment and the it disappears.

Comment: Wow. Any idea what what would overwrite the form value you load? Does the debug console provide any clues?

Comment: Added html and screen capture. Good luck with this problem.